# Conflict in Ctrl+f

Tags: autohotkey

I have a question about autohotkey. I confused at this problem for at least a month. I want to implement these key remap:

```
ctrl + f ==> right arrow
ctrl + shift + f ==> ctrl + f
```

But after I config:

```
^f::Send {Right}
^+f::Send ^f
```

Both `Ctrl+f` and `Ctrl+Shift+f` are equal to `Arrow right`.
So any people solve problems like this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume you meant the both sent arrow *right*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a similar answer [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/98284-how-to-swap-two-keys-colonsemicolon/). After that, here's what I use :

```
$^f::Send {Right}
$^+f::Send ^f
```

Just append `$` before, and it works perfectly! :-) I am so excited now.